# For AddScoped(), what is meant by "within the same HTTP request"

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand the difference between `AddSingleton`, `AddScoped` and `AddTransient`. There are lots of explanations but I can't understand them because I don't understand when an HTTP request is within the same scope

Comment: The instance that is given to you is unique to the current http request. If another request comes in, another instance is created for that request and so on. Every call to your backend (or server) is a new http request.

Comment: A HTTP request consists of Headers and a Body.  So when then mean "within" it is an additional header or within the body of the request.

Comment: @jdweng That's not what it means at all. You're describing what an HTTP request is, but that is not the same thing as executing in the context of an HTTP request within a web application, which is what the question is about. I suggest you remove your comment, because it's confusing to someone trying to figure out what is meant here.

Comment: @Silvermind, so every time an HTTP request is made by the client, that is classed as a new request? Thus a new instance is created for both transient and scoped objects. So I guess now I have to figure out the difference between these two. Thanks.

Comment: The difference between transient and scoped is: The scoped instance functions as some sort of singleton for the entire request. So every class within the request that resolves a scoped instance gets that same instance. A transient object is created new every time it is resolved, regardless of the current request.

Comment: @Silvermind, I think I understand it now. So If I passed the scoped object to another class or to a view, the same instance is being passed. For transient objects, a new one would be created. Am I correct?

Comment: Not if you pass it manually, only if it is resolved through dependency injection or when you manually call `ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>()`.

Comment: Finally. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to help. I would have loved to provide an answer with an example, but I'm not near a pc right now. A way you can try to understand what's happening is calling a `Console.WriteLine` in the three types of services' constructor and look what happens if you make multiple requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there's always a "root container" that's shared by all consumers in the AppDomain or running process. Child containers are then created for each HTTP request (in ASP.NET Core, for each `HttpContext` which encompasses `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse`). (Note that child containers can be created for other reasons too, but that's outside this answer's concern).

- `Singleton` services are only constructed once, usually only by the root container. They're like the Singleton-pattern in OOP (where a class can only be instantiated once), except in this case you can still manually create multiple instances, but the DI container will only ever create 1 instance itself.

  - You can use OOP Singletons with DI containers by returning the OOP singleton instance from a service factory method.
- `Transient` services are always created when they're requested - they're meant to be short-lived services. Some containers will call `IDisposable.Dispose` on all transient services it creates, others will not (as they expect the consumer to dispose of them, check with your container's policies).
- Request-scoped services can be implemented differently by different container systems - but a common approach I see is that at the start of each HTTP request (when a new `HttpContext` is created) a *child-container* is created (a child-container inherits the registrations of its parent) and then all of the objects it creates (often as singletons, but only in that child container) are then disposed (if applicable) when the HTTP request ends (when the `HttpContext` is destroyed, after the HTTP response has been sent to the client and the response ended).

Disregarding ASP.NET entirely - let's pretend we have our own HTTP server program with its own DI container:

```
public class HttpServer
{
    private readonly IContainer rootContainer;

    public HttpServer()
    {
        this.rootContainer = RegisterServices( new ContainerBuilder() ).Build();

    }

    private static IContainerBuilder RegisterServices( IContainerBuilder services )
    {
        return services
            .RegisterSingleton<ISystemClock,BiosClock>()
            .RegisterSingleton<MySingleton>( factory: () => MySingleton.Instance )
            .RegisterTransient<IDbConnection>( factory: () => new SqlConnection() )
            .RegisterRequest<RequestTracingService>();
    }

    public void OnHttpRequest( Socket socket )
    {
        HttpContext context = new HttpContext();
        context.RequestContainer = this.rootContainer.CreateChildContainer();

        try
        {
            // hand-off the `context` object to code that reads the request, does processing, and then writes the response
        }
        finally
        {
            context.RequestContainer.Dispose(); // <-- this disposes of any objects created by RequestContainer during the processing of the request, without touching any objects created by `rootContainer`.
        }
    }
}
```